# Memory and CPU assign to web application

Tags: java, memory-management, tomcat7, cpu-usage

How can we assign memory and CPU limit to any web application?
I am using java 6 and tomcat 7.
Please answer in all possible areas i.e config/programatic

Comment: When you say CPU limit, does that mean limiting the application to a certain number of virtual cores on the CPU?

Comment: No, I mean to say no. of request(thread) for web application.